# Should I tell my boss I am being headhunted in the hope that my current workplace may value me more? should I stay or should I go?

Tags: communication, job-change, negotiation, promotion, work-life-balance

The industry I work in is extremely small and hard to find replacement workers, which makes me very valuable to my boss especially because I am such a hard worker. We operate with two servicemen (including myself) two receptionists (one of whome is being let go next year and the other who is having their shifts decreased) and my boss.

In recent years, the lack of staff has made it difficult to get through the work load. However in the last 6months, I feel the boss has made some poor choices and the business has struggled to stay afloat. Making me uneasy about my job security.

That aside I work harder than anyone else in my workplace, I feel that I am worth more respect and money. I am over being questioned about my work when I was only following the bosses orders to begin with. I am sick and tired of the other service man always getting away with his poor performance, poor work ethic and attitude.

My boss seems to be lacking in addressing the issues affecting our company, even when I try to make suggestions or give advice they go unheard.
Ultimately I love my work but I am unhappy in my current job. My boss would really struggle without me but he has been good to me in the past and I feel obligated to be loyal to my boss and stay.

****Plot twist**** Another company has been trying to poach me for the last 6 months, to which I have declined several times. The new company would be happy to start me working straight away if I said yes. 
The reasons I have not taken the new job is because of my loyalty to my current boss, my hope that conditions will improve (even though that seems doubtful right now) and the fact that the new job may take me away from my family a bit more.

If I took the new job there would be no way of hiding it from my current boss as I would still work in the same facilities. 
I feel that I should be honest with my boss but I guess I am also hopeful that maybe my boss would take me more seriously and maybe would offer improving my current work conditions if he knew that he may loose me otherwise.

Could telling my current boss that I am being headhunted benefit me in anyway?
I am still in debate about weather I should put up with being unhappy or I should risk it all for a new job. But if conditions do not improve I cannot see myself in my current job for much longer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 3):

> Could telling my current boss that I am being headhunted benefit me in
>   anyway?

Short term - maybe.  Long term - most likely not.

> .. should risk it all for a new job

I'm not sure what you mean here.  Risk what exactly?

---

Any time you are unhappy in your job you should approach your manager and have a nice frank discussion with them.  There's no need to tell them about another opportunity - threats are never the way to maintain long term relationships and often will blow up in your face.  Rather you just want to let them know that you aren't happy in the current situation and explore how to fix it.

So, the first thing to do is put some serious thought into what types of changes would have to happen for you to be happy.  Be realistic.  **Then** approach your boss and try to work through them.  If the boss is unable or unwilling to make those changes *then* seek employment elsewhere.

At no point would I approach the boss and say "hey, this other company wants me and I'm going to go unless you do X, Y and Z."  That's the fastest way to be walked out and end the employment on bad terms.  Even if they don't walk you out immediately they will be looking to replace you at the first opportunity.

If you have a professional and frank discussion with the boss about things then they will know where you stand and, possibly, be able to resolve things.  Threatening them won't really make them want to work it out.

Comment: Short term: your boss starts to "like" you. Long term: while your boss suddenly "likes" you, he's actively looking for a replacement knowing that 90% of the time when this happens it means you're going to leave regardless of what he does.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest no-one is indispensable, if you leave then either they'll get by or they'll employ someone else. You'll be forgotten inside 6 months. Suggesting you are being headhunted is a bad move, just causes bad feeling all round.

There is absolutely no point in being unhappy, especially if you have options. Moving job is always a risk but that doesn't mean you cannot explore the opportunity, ask the right questions and make an informed decision. Even if the other job is not right for you then you may still see other possibilities and a new direction.

If you do move then the situation with your old boss could be difficult, depends on personalities and how you explain your reason for moving.